# Simple generator function and numpy not playing nice?

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools, functools

Suppose I have a simple generator function like this (I have a good reason to use numpy arrays, as the real case will involve some vector operations):

```
def testfun():
    x = np.array(0)
    while True:
        x += np.array(1)
        yield x
```

Take 10 first elements:

```
test = testfun()
test_slice = it.islice(test, 0, 10)
```

Now using .next() gives the values as expected from 1 to 10. But try to convert it to a list, and this happens:

```
list(test_slice)
out:
 [array(10),
 array(10),
 array(10),
 array(10),
 array(10),
 array(10),
 array(10),
 array(10),
 array(10),
 array(10)]
```

WTF?!?!

**If I modify the last line of the code to yield np.array(x), then the list conversion works just fine!** Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You keep `yield`ing references to **the same object**. `yield np.array(x)` creates a separate copy.

Comment: I don't get how the .next() method still works as intended...

Comment: `next` isn't any different.  Try `a = next(test_slice); b = next(test_slice); print a,b`.  It's simply that when you look one at a time, you see the changes to the array as they happen, as if you added `print x` inside the `while`.

Comment: It doesn't, really. When you look at it it appears correct, but if you keep a reference and check back after the iteration continues, it will change.

Comment: Well I still don't get it (I'm new to functional programming), but I'll figure it out. Thanks guys!

Comment: The code visualizer might help you: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice service mdurant, although it seems like numpy is not supported...